# How to use the jar of PrimeFaces-5.2.X using maven?

Tags: maven, jsf, primefaces, repository

The question seems easy, but according to my research, the maven repository http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/primefaces/primefaces/ has only  major releases 5.2,5.3,...,6,2

what I want exactly is to use the version **5.2.9** in order to correct the problem of the reCAPTCHA by implementing its v2, the use of the version 5.3 will have much impact on the developed application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X.Y.Z releases are only available for paying customers as an [elite release](https://www.primefaces.org/support/). You can then download the jar in a portal and put it in your own maven repo. They are not available in any public repository.

What you could try to do is to compare the sources of the 5.2 and 5.3 release regarding the captcha and just backport those. Still, really upgrading (to 6.2) is a better choice

Answer (score -1):

If you have luck, maybe 5.3.RC1, which implements reCAPTCHA v2, is close to 5.2.9. You can get 5.3.RC1 via primefaces repo: https://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/5.3.RC1/

Comment: I would never ever suggest to go with a 5.3RC1... It is waaay closer to 5.3 than to 5.2.9. 5.2.9 only contains some improvements and bugfixes while 5.3 (and its RC's) contains real changes as well. And since it is an RC it still contains issues that are fixed in the 5.3 CE release. Honestly a bad suggestion...