# Unable to download prime faces jar using maven

Tags: maven, primefaces

I want to download prime faces jar 5.2.21 ,which is required for my project but it is enable to download and facing below error, and I can able to download  prime faces 5.2 and 5.2 jar

```
    Pom.xml 
    
    <depency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>prime faces</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.21</version>
    </depency>
    
    Error:
    
    Missing artefacts org.primefaces:primefaces.jar 5.2.21
```

Comment: And please upvote the duplicate and ask within the company where they previously got the 5.2.21 release from.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing same letters in word "dependency"

this should work for you:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: That is just a wrong improper copy/paste action for which the poster should take very good care next time to not do that again. Otherwise you'd never get the error OP is getting. The issue is is that 5.2 elite release (al but the plain 5.2 community release are NOT in the maven repository) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304132/how-to-use-the-jar-of-primefaces-5-2-x-using-maven